# Installing Docker in Docker for CentOS results in HTTPS Error 404 - Not Found Error

Tags: docker, docker-compose, centos

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM base_company_repo

USER root

ENV http_proxy=proxy
ENV https_proxy=proxy
ENV no_proxy=proxy

COPY ./yum.conf /etc/yum.conf

RUN yum install -y yum-utils

RUN yum-config-manager \
    --add-repo \
    https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/docker-ce.repo

RUN yum install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io
```

In my `yum.conf` I only added a `timeout=300` parameter.

Building the image results in the following error and is cause by `RUN yum install -y yum-utils`:

> https://some_path_to_my_company/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 404 - Not Found

Do i need credentials like described here: https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora_Core/5/html/Software_Management_Guide/sn-yum-proxy-server.html ? I ask, because I do not have any and I wonder why I should need them.

I have also found a link to a redhat page, where I do not have access to: https://access.redhat.com/articles/1320623
Did anyone else have this problem and found a solution how to overcome that?

Comment: Can you access `https://some_path_to_my_company/repomd.xml` outside of Docker?

Comment: yes, but it forces me to enter a username and password. I don´t really understand this, because in no other repositories of my team anyone was forced use this and I nobody knows about possible passwords.
I guess I MIGHT have to add this to my `yum.conf`
`proxy_username=user`
`proxy_password=password`